# how to read a structure from .txt file in matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io, struct

I want to ask you for help in what follows:
I have couple of structures saved in a .txt file and I want to read them in matlab and save in a convenient type to load them later on into a .mat file. I've been searching through the internet to find a solution but what I got was info about reading columns, specific strings... but I cannot combine it to get the answer I want. Any help appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

here code I'm trying to work on:

```
struct
studentname: joe
notes:
n1 = 1.3
n2 = 2.0
average =1.7
endstruct

struct
studentname : marc
notes:
n1 = 2.3 %commentary, to be ommitted while reading from the file
n2 = 3.0
average = 2.7
endstruct
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a complete solution (similar to what [@Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10881725/97160) described):

```
%# read lines
fid = fopen('file.txt','rt');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter',''); C = C{1};
fclose(fid);

%# start/end of each structure
startIdx = find(ismember(C, 'struct'));
endIdx = find(ismember(C, 'endstruct'));

%# array of strucutres
N = numel(startIdx);
arr = struct('studentname','', 'notes','', 'n1',0, 'n2',0, 'average',0);
arr = repmat(arr,[N 1]);

%# parse and store each structure in the array
for i=1:numel(startIdx)
    %# parse key/value of struct
    s = C(startIdx(i)+1:endIdx(i)-1);
    s = regexp(s, '(\w+)\s*[:=]\s*([^%$]*)(?:%[^$]*)?', 'tokens', 'once');
    s = vertcat(s{:});

    %# try to parse as numbers
    v = str2double(s(:,2));
    s(~isnan(v),2) = num2cell(v(~isnan(v)));

    %# store: struct.key = value
    for j=1:size(s,1)
        arr(i).(s{j,1}) = s{j,2};
    end
end
```

The result:

```
>> arr(1)
ans = 
    studentname: 'joe'
          notes: ''
             n1: 1.3
             n2: 2
        average: 1.7
>> arr(2)
ans = 
    studentname: 'marc'
          notes: ''
             n1: 2.3
             n2: 3
        average: 2.7
```

Of course this assumes the file is well formatted (struct/endstruct blocks, all structs contain the same fields, and field types are consistent)

---

#### Explanation:

The code starts by reading the file lines into a cell array. Then we look for the start/end position of struct/endstruct constructs. We initialize an empty array of structure with some default values, and we iterate through the file parsing each block, and storing that info in one structure.

Next we use [regular](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html) [expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to detect the following pattern:

```
some_key_name = some value  % optional comment here
```

we allow for some variations in spaces, and also accept either `=` or `:` as character in between. We use capturing tokens in regexp to recover each component of the above, and store them in a temporary cell array. At this point, everything is stored as strings.

Now that actual values can either be numeric or strings. We initially try to parse them as numbers using STR2DOUBLE. This function returns `NaN` if it fails, which we use to change only the parts that were successfully converted.

Finally with the above result, we use dynamic field names to store each value in the corresponding key inside the structure array.

Comment: Thanks so much!
If you can please add some comments what are these operations for:
v = str2double(s(:,2));
    s(~isnan(v),2) = num2cell(v(~isnan(v)));
I don't understand well enough how can I improve this code, for when I'm saving in .mat file, it saves only the last structure, all previous are overwritten. Is it the solution to put save function in a loop or rather to create somehow differently the cell arrays to save data?

I also cannot understand the complicated amount of expressions for the token :( 
'(\w+)\s*[:=]\s*([^%$]*)(?:%[^$]*)?'

If can explain, please :)

Comment: I'll try to add more explanations shortly... Now to save the parsed structures, call: `save file.mat arr`. To load the data from file afterward, a simple `load file.mat` will do.

Comment: Thank you, it's clear. What if I want to read structures that have a various number of notes in the field note? Notes should be then an inner structure inside the main structure. How can I read the notes dnamically? I was thinking about writing the same code once again, inside a loop, but since it should be flexible, i.e. user doesn't have to know how many notes are inside and what are their names... how to do it?

Comment: @beginh: that's a completely different specification. I recommend you create a new question..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are basically going to have to roll your own.  You can start with [`fileread()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileread.html), which reads the entire file into a string, then, reading line by line, maybe using [`regexp()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) or [`strfind()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html) to parse each line, then finally using either [`struct()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) or [`dynamic field access`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br1v5cc-1.html) to construct your structs.

Untested, incomplete, but rough idea (presumes file is well-formed - you will need to add checks):

```
%read file
wholeFile = fileread(myfilename);

%find starts & ends:
starts = strfind(wholeFile, 'struct');
ends = strfind(wholeFile, 'endstruct');

For i = 1:numel(starts);
    rawStruct = wholeFile(starts(i)+7, ends(i)-2);
    %parse line by line getting field names using the string "rawStruct"
    out(i).(fieldname) = content;
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You could give the [XML_io_tools](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools) from the Matlab file exchange a try. It can parse a XML file to a matlab struct and visa versa.

Comment: So? It might be easier turning a text file into an xml file rather than writing your own parser.

Comment: @Maurits I didn't downvote, but I think you're wrong. I find it hard to believe that if you've already done the job of parsing the text file, then generating an XML file would be easier than storing it in the desired struct array.